# How do multiple servers increase throughput for network requests?

Tags: networking

This is a question that has been going through my head for around two years now that I've never really slowed down and taken the time to ask, mainly because I've been using cloud services instead of having to manage my own servers up until now.

It's quite common for companies to refer to Linear / Horizontal scaling in which when things get a little tough they just throw more machines at the server application to increase throughput. Requests will be handled by one of the many machines supplied and responded to the client. In most cases what I've read about this is that the request/connection and associated data is forwarded to the device that is supposed to handle the specific connection/request based on the used algorithm.

This all sounds well in theory, but isn't there a **single point of failure/limitation**? If there's a single application routing all of these requests (Thinking REST requests here) to the machine that's supposed to handle it, isn't there still one machine that is receiving and handling every single request? It doesn't matter if you have 5 machines or 20 if there is a single machine processing every request and handing it off to one of the other machines for processing. This seems like a horrible implementation, because it doesn't do anything in terms of increasing throughput, but it's the one I read about most.

How I've always invisioned this being done is that there's a single server that handles deciding which machine should handle your requests to which you will initiate a GET request to on startup. This request would resolve with the information about the server that you're supposed to be talking to. Every 5 minutes or so you will send another GET request to the server to see if you should change servers, and always send a GET request to obtain a new server on any network errors.  This will ensure that you are never trying to communicate with an offline server, and that the only request going to the "Handoff server" as I would like to call it, is the one asking what server we should talk to. This handoff server should be connected to each individual server through a keep-alive TCP connection and make sure that the server is running. In the event that a server goes offline, a new server would be recommended for the client.  This way even though a machine goes down, the end-user would never notice it.

There's two core differences between the information that I've read on the matter, and how I would think it works, and that's the amount of request processing for the "Handoff server" whereas my implementation only requires a minimal amount of requests, and the one I always read about requests the handoff server to handle every single request.

Comment: Please consider moving this question to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

> How do multiple servers increase throughput for network requests?

Well, fundamentally, that's a resource available calculation. 
Each node used in a given service has a limited amount of CPU time, RAM, and network bandwidth available.

So multiple servers increase the throughput by making more resources available to perform the same task. 
How the task is distributed is a separate issue - but the fundamentals are that more servers have more resources to do a given job, and so when we need to do more of a given job, we assign the required resources.

The horizontal scaling is generally mentioned in contrast to how things were done before we could throw n+1 machines at a problem easily - i.e. the days when you had to order a whole new piece of hardware if your current hardware wasn't able to keep up.  That tended to result in needing to spec a machine to handle something between average load and peak load, which in turn tended to result in some unused capacity.

I suspect this part of the answer isn't really what you were asking, though.

> This all sounds well in theory, but isn't there a single point of failure/limitation?

Ultimately, yes, there is always *some* single point of failure, but the answer in context is that this is a design choice.

What you are basically describing is some kind of load-balancer or reverse proxy in front of your backend server pool. 
In which case, yes, if you have only one machine doing that, it is a single point of failure.

The 'obvious' counterpoint is: use more such front-end machines to avoid the single point of failure. 
How that works depends:

- you can use DNS (which you can also use to round-robin between backends without involving a front end). A simple example being a CNAME or SRV pointing to several different A records.
- you can use a HA setup, possibly based on virtual IPs (anycast is maybe worth putting into this 'category') - for example, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-web-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04.

You can also combine those two techniques, and add various tools and approaches to try and avoid the SPOF actually failing in the first place, but in general, a single point of failure will live up to its name, and so it is considered best practice to avoid building such a point of failure into your design in the first place.

Or, to give a much shorter answer: you can scale your front-end/request router/load-balancer in the same way you can the servers running your application. If you are concerned about availability, I think it wouldn't be over-generalising to say you would typically start with at least a pair of each component to avoid building a single point of failure into your application.

Answer (score 0):

its called a load balancer usually its a cluster with HA if the cluster of load balancers fail then you have redundancy at another site usually with another set of load balancers.

this is why there is no single point of failure because the load balancers "check each other out" and also check that the nodes are up for the service requested tru "monitoring probes" so they know if the node is down or not. 
because its much easier to have a dedicated appliance "switch the packet" to the available node this increase the output . since the load balancers can also be alternated in HA this allows fore more throughput without single point of failures.